# can not get autocompletion to work with bootstrap and php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to get an auto completed text field.
nothing seems to work with me (i am Using Codeigniter for a back end and Bootstrap for styling).
When testing any plugin in a page without bootstrap theme css. it works like a charm, 
but at the moment i link some bootstrap in that page, it stops.

i have used so far:
1. The built-in typeahead plugin.
2. jquery-ui autocomplete widget.
3. jquery textExt.
4. and a couple more

so i am out of solutions .. can anyone help ?

Comment: if you do not paste any piece of code we can't help you, jquery ui is simple to use, if you set the ajax url to receive the data back you should not have any problem !

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957781/google-maps-autocomplete-result-in-bootstrap-modal-dialog

Answer (score 0):

- Check to see if the classname of your autocomplete widget collides with any of Bootstrap's.
- Do you have a link to the site you're working on? if so, that will be more usefull in providing you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and use the return values from the server as a JSON Format. First read this docs and then change as per codeigniter rules of passing jSON data to view. When your json data pass
successfully to the view you are able to use typehead.

**Note:-Basic Need of typehead.js in Twitter Bootstrap first.**

> http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/typehead.php