# Bootstrap 3 - navbar issue when it's fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-places-api, navbar, input-field

With Bootstrap 3 navigation bar, I want to display Google place options on an input text field. Following is the screen shot for same:

[image]

As can be seen from screen shots, when `navbar` is fixed, options are displayed at the back. And, when `navbar` is static, options are displayed as expected. I want the options to be displayed properly when navbar is fixed.

I tried to point the code on bootply but, it's not working. Working code at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sannidhi/WLQjp/). Also, code is as under:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

  </head>

  <body style="min-height:      2000px;">

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Find <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="search" style="width: 20em;" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>



    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<script>

    window.onload = function() {

        var options = {
            types: ['geocode']
        };

        var inputField;     
        inputField = document.getElementsByName( 'search' )[0];
        new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( inputField, options );

    };

</script>
```

Please help.

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the z-index of your elements. Try changing the z-index of .pac-container. Example: .pac-container { z-index: 9999; }.

Comment: I suppose z-index is common for all types of navigations' bar. The only change between two outputs is class, one is 'navbar-fixed-top' and other is 'navbar-static-top'. Thanks for pointing about JSFiddle, code on it @ http://jsfiddle.net/sannidhi/WLQjp/.

Comment: Just tried to edit the fiddle and it is exactly what i said it was :) increase z-index of pac-container `.pac-container { z-index: 9999;}` try this.

Comment: Cool, that works! But, pls help me understand what's pac-container as I do not find it in either of two bootstrap files.

Comment: i haven't looked at it too much in detail right now but it is the class of the div that contains the suggestions of country/city names i think it might have come from plugin or script that you are using to load those suggestions and as it has a google logo at the end of it so may be it is from some external script not bootstrap :)

Comment: All: A value of >= `1030` for `z-index` of `pac-container` class will work.

Comment: All: Another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957781/google-maps-autocomplete-result-in-bootstrap-modal-dialog) of interest.